# Let $f$ be a twice differential function on the open interval $(-1,1)$ such that $f(0)=1$. Show that $f'(0) ≥ -\sqrt2$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Q. Let $f$ be a twice differential function on the open interval $(-1,1)$ such that $f(0) = 1$. Suppose $f$ also satisfies $f(x) ≥ 0$, $f'(x) ≤ 0$ and $f″(x) ≤ f(x)$, for all $x ≥ 0$. Show that
$f'(0) ≥ -\sqrt{2}$.

My attempt:
Since, $f'(x) ≤ 0$ and $f″(x) ≤ f(x)$. So, $f(x)$ is a decreasing and a concave down function. Now, if we draw a tangent to the function at $x=0$, it will always be above the function. Checking the value of ordinate for the tangent and the function at $x=1$, we get:
$f'(0) > -1$. But, I am not able to prove $f'(0) ≥ -\sqrt{2}$.
Please help me out..

Comment: Your reasoning is incorrect. $f(x) = e^{-x}$ satisfies each of the conditions but is concave up.

Comment: $f(x) = 1$ satisfies your conditions, so the conclusion does not hold.

Comment: @gt6989b why had you deleted all the information from the question and asking me how did I knew so and so..?

Comment: @Utkarsh did not seem like i deleted it...

Comment: @Arthur you function does not satisfy $f(x) \ge 0 \ \forall x > 0$

Comment: @gt6989b my editing section shows me u have deleted 36 characters in body;edited tags; edited title..what does that mean??

Comment: i have reformatted your question to typeset it with LaTeX, which is the std for this site. it did not seem like i deleted content, just replaced with reformatted text. But to a text editor it seems as a deletion.

Comment: @Utkarsh Arthur just added Mathjax formatting. You should learn it and use it, instead of reverting to your bad formatting.

Comment: @UmbertoP thank you so much for letting me know my mistake. But, I am still stuck how to solve it..

Comment: @gt6989b thank you for reformatting. But, I am just asking you why had you removed the essential contents from the question. It had famished the real essence of the question

Comment: Already asked, already answered. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329309/prove-that-f0-ge-sqrt2-for-a-function-f-satisfying-some-conditions/1329396#1329396

Comment: @LandonCarter thank you so much for sharing this beautiful information.