# Prove that if $f''(x)≤f(x)$ , then $ f'(x)<\sqrt{2}f(x)$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, derivatives, inequality

I need help with this problem,
"Let $f\in\mathcal{C}^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(x)$, $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ are all strictly positive for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that if $f''(x)\leq f(x)$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $f'(x)<\sqrt{2}f(x)$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$"

I apologize if it seems like I'm asking you to do my work, but I honestly don't know where to begin with this...

Comment: You should tell us what you know, why you are interested in this problem, and be more specific about what’s causing the confusion.

Comment: Hint: try differentiating the function $\frac{f'}{f}$.

Comment: It is a shame that the question got closed and the OP seems unwilling to improve it, because I think it is a very interesting question. Nevertheless, it has been indirectly answered in the following: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1072950/443030; by considering the function $g_x(t) = f(x-t)/f(x)$ and applying the result above to $g_x$, we get the desired result.